# Unable to run Android emulator (BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation))

Tags: android, runtime-error, emulation, execution, bad-alloc

I am unable to run my android emulator. When I run the app I get the following in the console:

```
/home/thom/Programs/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_23 -netspeed full -netdelay none
X Error of failed request:  BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  149 ()
  Minor opcode of failed request:  2
  Serial number of failed request:  35
  Current serial number in output stream:  36
```

I've found many similar errors but I can't find a solution that applies to my error.

Answer (score 0):

Install 32bit graphic driver.
lib32-mesa-libgl xf86-video-intel  mesa-libgl  libva-intel-driver libva

For Archlinux, enable multilib in pacman.conf and

> sudo pacman -S lib32-mesa-libgl xf86-video-intel  mesa-libgl  libva-intel-driver libva

Comment: How about Debian/Ubuntu?